# Can't install any other libraries anymore in node_modules, evertime I got the same error while install libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules

### I Got This error after I run npm audit --force, My whole Node_module dependency messed up

0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

1 info using npm@8.13.2

2 info using node@v16.16.0

3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms

4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms

5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms

6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms

7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms

8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms

9 timing
config:load:file:C:\Users\Jenis\OneDrive\Documents\Final_Year_Project\The_app\The_restaurant
_app.npmrc Completed in 0ms

10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms

11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Jenis.npmrc Completed in 0ms

12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms

13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms

14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms

15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms

16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms

17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms

18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms

19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms

20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms

21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms

22 verbose title npm install @twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input

23 verbose argv "install" "--save" "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input"

24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms

25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms

26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms

27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs

28 verbose logfile C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-08T19_46_57_590Z-
debug-0.log

29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 3ms

30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms

31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms

32 timing npm:load Completed in 14ms

33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms

34 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files

35 silly logfile done cleaning log files

36 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json out of date, updated:
node_modules

37 timing idealTree:init Completed in 1107ms

38 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms

39 silly idealTree buildDeps

40 silly fetch manifest @twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input@*

41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@twotalltotems%2freact-native-otp-input
472ms (cache hit)

42 silly placeDep ROOT @twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input@1.3.11 OK for:
the_restaurant_app@1.0.0 want: *

43 silly fetch manifest @react-native-community/clipboard@^1.2.2

44 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-native-community%2fclipboard 762ms
(cache hit)

45 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 1243ms

46 silly fetch manifest react@>=16.0

47 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 21ms (cache hit)

48 silly fetch manifest react-native@>=0.57.0

49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native 7ms (cache hit)

50 silly fetch manifest react@18.0.0

51 silly placeDep ROOT @react-native-community/clipboard@1.5.1 OK for: @twotalltotems/react-
native-otp-input@1.3.11 want: ^1.2.2

52 timing idealTree:node_modules/@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input Completed in 50ms

53 timing idealTree:node_modules/@react-native-community/clipboard Completed in 0ms

54 silly fetch manifest react-native-safe-area-context@^3.1.9

55 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-safe-area-context 7ms (cache
hit)

56 silly fetch manifest react@*

57 silly fetch manifest react-native@*

58 timing idealTree Completed in 2420ms

59 timing command:install Completed in 2427ms

60 verbose stack Error: could not resolve

60 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.failPeerConflict
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\place
-dep.js:549:25)

60 verbose stack     at PlaceDep.place
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\place
-dep.js:199:21)

60 verbose stack     at new PlaceDep
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\place
-dep.js:73:10)

60 verbose stack     at
C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arbori
st\build-ideal-tree.js:990:31

60 verbose stack     at Array.map ()

60 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDepStep]
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arbor
ist\build-ideal-tree.js:990:8)

60 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arbor
ist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)

60 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)

60 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arbor
ist\reify.js:153:5)

60 verbose stack     at async Install.exec
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:145:5)

60 verbose stack     at async module.exports
(C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)

61 verbose cwd
C:\Users\Jenis\OneDrive\Documents\Final_Year_Project\The_app\The_restaurant_app

62 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000

63 verbose node v16.16.0

64 verbose npm  v8.13.2
65 error code ERESOLVE

66 error ERESOLVE could not resolve

67 error

68 error While resolving: [1mreact-native-elements[22m@[1m3.4.2[22m

68 error Found: [1mreact-native-safe-area-context[22m@[1m4.2.4[22m[2m[22m

68 error [2mnode_modules/react-native-safe-area-context[22m

68 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact-native-safe-area-context[22m@"[1m>= 3.0.0[22m" from
[1m@react-navigation/bottom-tabs[22m@[1m6.3.1[22m[2m[22m

68 error   [2mnode_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs[22m

68 error     [1m@react-navigation/bottom-tabs[22m@"[1m^6.3.1[22m" from the root project

68 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact-native-safe-area-context[22m@"[1m>= 3.0.0[22m" from
[1m@react-navigation/elements[22m@[1m1.3.3[22m[2m[22m

68 error   [2mnode_modules/@react-navigation/elements[22m

68 error     [1m@react-navigation/elements[22m@"[1m^1.3.3[22m" from [1m@react-
navigation/bottom-tabs[22m@[1m6.3.1[22m[2m[22m

68 error     [2mnode_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs[22m

68 error       [1m@react-navigation/bottom-tabs[22m@"[1m^6.3.1[22m" from the root
project

68 error     [1m@react-navigation/elements[22m@"[1m^1.3.3[22m" from [1m@react-
navigation/stack[22m@[1m6.2.1[22m[2m[22m

68 error     [2mnode_modules/@react-navigation/stack[22m

68 error       [1m@react-navigation/stack[22m@"[1m^6.2.1[22m" from the root project

68 error   4 more (@react-navigation/stack, native-base, ...)

68 error

68 error Could not resolve dependency:

68 error [35mpeer[39m [1mreact-native-safe-area-context[22m@"[1m^3.1.9[22m" from
[1mreact-native-elements[22m@[1m3.4.2[22m[2m[22m

68 error [2mnode_modules/react-native-elements[22m

68 error   [1mreact-native-elements[22m@"[1m^3.4.2[22m" from the root project

68 error

68 error Conflicting peer dependency: [1mreact-native-safe-area-
context[22m@[1m3.4.1[22m[2m[22m

68 error [2mnode_modules/react-native-safe-area-context[22m

68 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact-native-safe-area-context[22m@"[1m^3.1.9[22m" from
[1mreact-native-elements[22m@[1m3.4.2[22m[2m[22m

68 error   [2mnode_modules/react-native-elements[22m

68 error     [1mreact-native-elements[22m@"[1m^3.4.2[22m" from the root project

68 error

68 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

68 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

68 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

68 error

68 error See C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

69 verbose exit 1

70 timing npm Completed in 2513ms

71 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1657309617667

72 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1657309617672

73 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1657309618783

74 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:node_modules/react-native-elements 1657309620076

75 verbose code 1

76 error A complete log of this run can be found in:

76 error     C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-08T19_46_57_590Z-debug-
0.log

Comment: Have you tried the common stuff like npm ci, npm cache clean --force, delete node_modules and package-lock file and then run npm install?

Comment: I tried npm cash clean --force but it says Recommended protections disabled. also, I tried to delete node_module and package-lock, it was a horrible mistake I did because somehow my npm can't get back those data, I got a bunch of error that looks similar to the upper one.

Comment: It really sounds like that your local npm cache is bad. Can you try manually to delete this directory? C:\Users\Jenis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\. Otherwise reinstall nodejs.

Comment: I tried to reinstall nodejs, but got the same error while running npm install

Answer (score 0):

I still got the errors while installing the libraries but I using `npm install <package> --force` will be installing my libraries